# What is the difference between machine software interrupt and environment call from M-mode?

Tags: riscv

How to trigger a machine software interrupt?
Is it different from environment call from M-mode?

| Interrupt | Exception Code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Reserved |
| 1 | 1 | Supervisor software interrupt |
| 1 | 2 | Reserved |
| 1 | 3 | Machine software interrupt |
| 1 | 4 | Reserved |
| 1 | 5 | Supervisor timer interrupt |
| 1 | 6 | Reserved |
| 1 | 7 | Machine timer interrupt |
| 1 | 8 | Reserved |
| 1 | 9 | Supervisor external interrupt |
| 1 | 10 | Reserved |
| 1 | 11 | Machine external interrupt |
| 1 | 12–15 | Reserved |
| 1 | ≥16 | Designated for platform use |
| 0 | 0 | Instruction address misaligned |
| 0 | 1 | Instruction access fault |
| 0 | 2 | Illegal instruction |
| 0 | 3 | Breakpoint |
| 0 | 4 | Load address misaligned |
| 0 | 5 | Load access fault |
| 0 | 6 | Store/AMO address misaligned |
| 0 | 7 | Store/AMO access fault |
| 0 | 8 | Environment call from U-mode |
| 0 | 9 | Environment call from S-mode |
| 0 | 10 | Reserved |
| 0 | 11 | Environment call from M-mode |
| 0 | 12 | Instruction page fault |
| 0 | 13 | Load page fault |
| 0 | 14 | Reserved |
| 0 | 15 | Store/AMO page fault |
| 0 | 16–23 | Reserved |
| 0 | 24–31 | Designated for custom use |
| 0 | 32–47 | Reserved |
| 0 | 48–63 | Designated for custom use |
| 0 | ≥64 | Reserved |

How to trigger a machine software interrupt? Is it different from environment call from M-mode?

Answer (score 1):

After reading [SiFive FU540-C000 Manual v1p4](https://starfivetech.com/uploads/fu540-c000-manual-v1p4.pdf), I know that machine software interrupt is truly different from environment call from M-mode.

- Environment call is triggered by `ecall` instruction.
- Software interrupt is triggered by wrtiring a specified memory-mapped register.

From [SiFive FU540-C000 Manual v1p4](https://starfivetech.com/uploads/fu540-c000-manual-v1p4.pdf) Page 66

> 9.2 MSIP Registers
> Machine-mode software interrupts are generated by writing to the memory-mapped control register msip. Each msip register is a 32-bit wide WARL register where the upper 31 bits are tied to 0. The least significant bit is reflected in the MSIP bit of the mip CSR. Other bits in the msip registers are hardwired to zero. On reset, each msip register is cleared to zero.
> Software interrupts are most useful for interprocessor communication in multi-hart systems, as
> harts may write each other’s msip bits to effect interprocessor interrupts.